# What's a more detailed ui mock-up tool to use, rather than balsamiq

Tags: user-interface

I currently use [balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) for ui mock ups, but sometimes it does not give me the detail I need for more specific functionality I want to show. e.g. Error messages, validation.

Is there a similar, easy to use tool that allows more customisation than balsamiq's drag and drop?

(I still plan to use balsamiq for simple mock-ups, as I like it. It's quick and easy to use)

Comment: I've found this tool http://www.gliffy.com/ which lets you mockup screens quite easily. Shame you have to register to be able to save progress, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and searched, but yet to find a suitable mockup tool - saying that Balsamiq meets almost all my requirements so have used that exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Not as simple to get going with but far more powerful is [Expression Sketchflow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow_Overview.aspx)

Comment: I have had that demoed to me by a colleague, and I agree it is a lot more powerful! I think I want something slightly less complicated, as Sketchflow creates a prototype at the same time, which I don't see as beneficial for my use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out iRise? It's rather cool, altho not cheap.